# NoClassDefFoundError Exception in web app with Maven 3 and Hibernate 5

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, tomcat8

I have my web application that has the backend in `Java` and works with `Hibernate`, `Jackson` (for the json parser) and `Jersey` for the Rest API. The problem comes when i run the server (`Tomcat 8`) i got a `NoDefClassFoundException` saying that the `Persistence` class cannot be found, but is weird because i have the `Hibernate 5.2.7` dependency (that's suppose to have included the jpa implementation of that class) and i don't know why i'm still getting this error. If i look into the `Maven` dependencies i see the `org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api` dependency with the  `javax.persistence` package with `Persistence` class there. I leave you the error log and the project tree so you can see the dependencies Maven has downloaded. I'm working with `IntelliJ 2016.3.3`, i don't know if that is important in this case but just in case.

Any help would be awesome and very appreciate.

Error log:

```
30-Jan-2017 01:06:09.404 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Excepción enviando evento inicializado de contexto a instancia de escuchador de clase controllers.MissingDogListener
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence
    at util.JPAUtil.buildEntityManagerFactory(JPAUtil.java:15)
    at controllers.MissingDogListener.contextInitialized(MissingDogListener.java:26)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4842)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1696)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:484)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:433)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    ... 47 more

30-Jan-2017 01:06:09.409 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Excepción enviando evento de contexto destruído a instancia de escuchador de clase controllers.MissingDogListener
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory
    at util.JPAUtil.shutdown(JPAUtil.java:30)
    at controllers.MissingDogListener.contextDestroyed(MissingDogListener.java:18)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4889)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5526)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1696)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:484)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:433)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    ... 48 more
```

Project tree:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Cd0R.png
(I can't upload images because of my score)

`pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MissingDog</groupId>
  <artifactId>MissingDog</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>MissingDog Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- JUnit -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- PostgreSQL Driver -->
      <!-- postgresql -->
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>9.4.1212</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- End PostgreSQL Driver -->

    <!-- hibernate-core -->
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
          <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
      </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson -->
      <!-- jackson-annotations -->
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.6</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- jackson-core -->
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.6</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- jackson-databind -->
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- End Jackson -->

    <!-- Jersey -->
    <!-- javax.ws.rs-api -->
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.1</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- jersey-client -->
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
          <version>2.25</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- jersey-container-servlet -->
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
          <version>2.25</version>
      </dependency>

     <!-- jersey-server -->
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
          <version>2.25</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
      </dependency>
   <!-- End Jersey -->

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>MissingDog</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include this dependency, clean and build then run

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: how do i clean and build from intellij?? or i need to do that from the console?

Comment: This link may help you https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/executing-maven-goal.html or google it

Comment: if i add the hibernate-jpa-2.1-api dependency explicitly it founds the Persistence class, but instead throw me the NoSuchMethodError on the "createQuery(String qlString, Class<T> resultClass)" version of the method...

Comment: any idea @vels4j?? i really apreciate the help

Comment: you need to provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
what is your goal?

Comment: i don't speak very much english... my goal is obtain a solution for this problem... i search on every post of stackoverflow that i found and i can't work out a solution...